# How to evaluate stationary bicycle resistance

Tags: cardio, exercise-equipment, home-exercise, resistance

I would like to understand how to evaluate the resistance range of a stationary bicycle before buying online, as I have maxed out the resistance on my current one.

All of the bicycles I see online speak in terms of arbitrary levels.
If possible, I would like to avoid buying one, trying it, and returning it over and over again.

I really am trying to understand how to understand the resistance range of a stationary exercise bicycle.  (I tried contacting some manufacturers, but the online chat people either did not know or did not understand my question.).

It feels like I am asking the wrong question at this point.  That I am looking at the wrong thing.

I have maxed out the resistance on my current bicycle (Schwinn 170)
I have had my stationary bicycle for several years.
I ride at a fixed resistance for fixed time and keep the RPMs between 100-110.
Over time, I have slowly increased the resistance, but I have gotten to the max level.
I am not interested in online classes (exercising with other people)

Comment: Does Schwinn have an options for modifying a bike to add more resistance? Good question though.